# Create a class with array of objects

Tags: c#

Code below defines a ChargeCustomer class that contains an array of type "customers". I want to be able to create an object with either 1 "customer" or 2 "customers" based on the constructor parameters. Is this the right way to do so in C#:

```
public class ChargeCustomer 
{
    private Customer[] customers;

    public ChargeCustomer( string aName, string bName, int charge )
    {
        customers = new Customer[2];
        customers[0] = new Customer(aName, charge);
        customers[1] = new Customer(bName, charge);  
    }

    public ChargeCustomer( string bName, int charge )
    {
        customers = new Customer[1];
        customers[0] = new Customer( bName, charge );
    }
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: Does `DropBox` derive from `Customer`? If not, you can't store it in a `Customer` array.

Comment: that is correct, however, you are limited to only be able to create 1 or 2 customers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Note: This assumes that `DropBox` was a mis-paste in the original question.*

You can move things around and have 1 constructor using [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) for any number of names, like this:

```
public class ChargeCustomer 
{
  private Customer[] customers;

  public ChargeCustomer( int charge, params string[] names)
  {
    customers = new Customer[names.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++) {
      customers[i] = new Customer(names[i], charge);
    }
  }
}
```

Using this approach you just pass the charge first and any number of customer names, like this:

```
new ChargeCustomer(20, "Bill", "Joe", "Ned", "Ted", "Monkey");
```

It will create an array the correct size and fill it using the same charge for all, and 1 Customer per name by looping through the names passed in.  All that being said, there's probably a much simpler overall solution to your problem, but without making changes outside the Customer class (aside from the constructor calls), this would be the simplest approach/smallest change.